# iOS - Cannot call API when app is running background

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing an application that allows users to enter surveys. Application can work when offline/online.

**Here is the concept:**

1. In case of online: When user enter survey and click on submit button, the app will call api (using `httpClient`) to send survey info to server.
2. In case of offline: When user enter survey and click on submit button, the app will save survey info in local. After the mobile device connected network, it will call api to send survey info from local to server.

**Workflow:**

- For android, it works for these cases:

  **When online:** - Create survey, survey will be sent to server.

  **When offline:**

  1. Create survey => survey is saved at local;
     1.1. Keep app is still opening and then connect network => survey is sent to server;
         1.2. Touch home button so app run background => Connect network => survey is sent to server;
         1.3. Users force-quit app => Connect network (in this case survey wont be sent to server) => Open app (survey will be synced to server)
- For iOS, it works for these cases:

  **When online:** Create survey, survey will be sync to server (need to wait about 5 seconds before closed app. Because if closed immediately, it will error when calling api).

  **When offline:**

  1. Create survey => survey is saved at local.
         1.1. Keep app is still opening and then connect network => survey is sent to server;
         1.2. Touch home button so app run background => Connect network (in this case survey wont be sent to server) => Open app (survey will be sent to server);
         1.3. Users force-quit app => Connect network (in this case survey wont be sent to server) => Open app (survey will be sent to server)

So I see that everything works fine on Android.
However, there was a problem if the app run the background on iOS. Survey is only sent to the server if users open the app.
For iOS, I'm using Silent Notification. Will push Notification to the app every 5 minutes to trigger calling API (send survey to server) when the app is running background. For now, the app can call API when app receive notification but there is an error occurred while calling api.

- I have used my iPhone and tested on Facebook Messenger, in case I send a message while offline and then touch the Home button to run background (not force-quit app). After network was connected, the message will be sent without having to open the app.

**Here is the error:**

> NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[URL], NSErrorFailingURLKey=[URL],
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x104e298d0 +
>   0x0091f> in
>   :0 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker
>   (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request,
>   System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x104de7dd0 +
>   0x00423> in
>   <51ea6b8d5ff1420888885e4cb6c720e9#ca5a74421adead0e302c060b720be5bb>:0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.RestClient.PostAsync[T,TP] (System.String url, TP
>   t, System.Nullable 1[T] token) <0x105c15460 + 0x00984> in
>   :0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.SyncService.Push
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[T] synchronizations) <0x105c1d7a0
>   + 0x001e7> in :0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.SyncService.PushSurveys () <0x105c1d1b0 +
>   0x0028b> in
>   :0
>   ","System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException The network connection was
>   lost.   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync
>   (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x104e298d0 +
>   0x0091f> in
>   :0 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker
>   (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request,
>   System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x104de7dd0 +
>   0x00423> in
>   <51ea6b8d5ff1420888885e4cb6c720e9#ca5a74421adead0e302c060b720be5bb>:0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.RestClient.PostAsync[T,TP] (System.String url, TP
>   t, System.Nullable 1[T] token) <0x105c15460 + 0x00984> in
>   :0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.SyncService.Push
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[T] synchronizations) <0x105c1d7a0
>   + 0x001e7> in :0 
>   at SurveyApp.Service.SyncService.PushSurveys () <0x105c1d1b0 +
>   0x0028b> in
>   :0 
>   Foundation.NSErrorException Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005
>   ""The network connection was lost."" Use

**Here is code that I'm handling for calling API (use httpClient):**

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T, TP>(string url, TP t, CancellationToken? token = null)
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(content);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), DefaultRequestHeaders = { ConnectionClose = true } })
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

            if (token != null)
            {
                responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent, token.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request has problem");
            }

            var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent, DefaultSerializerSettings);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return await PostAsync<T, TP>(url, t, token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(e);
        throw;
    }
}

public async Task<T> PostSurveyPhotoWithDataAsync<T>(string url, string file, SurveyPhoto surveyPhoto)
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), DefaultRequestHeaders = { ConnectionClose = true } })
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    formData.Add(new StreamContent(streamReader.BaseStream), "File", file);
                    formData.Add(new StringContent(surveyPhoto.KeyId), "KeyId");
                    formData.Add(new StringContent(surveyPhoto.FileName), "FileName");
                    formData.Add(new StringContent(surveyPhoto.SurveySyncId), "SurveyId");

                    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                    var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, formData, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                    streamReader.Close();

                    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Request has problem");
                    }

                    var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent, DefaultSerializerSettings);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return await PostSurveyPhotoWithDataAsync<T>(url, file, surveyPhoto);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there any solution, document or sample code that can help me solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please try add a little delay before call SyncData(); as mentioned in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/393172/#Comment_393172)? People there are trying to do the same thing as you. Also make sure that you have enabled background modes (background fetch and remote notifications).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jack. 
- I tried but seem as it not work.
- And there is another issue, the app cannot receive Silent Notification after I disabled network and enable network again.
It only receive if I open app (Foreground) again, and it also can receive after I gone to background then. Do you know why?

Comment: It seems your app hangs up after go to background and did not reconnect after enable network again.

Comment: Thanks for your support, thank you very much, Jack.

Comment: No problem, you find the solution?

Comment: I still haven't found out solution. For now, my solution is show Notification on device and user will tap on it to open app to sync data to the server (because sync (httpClient call api) only work if app is opening). I'm using Silent Notification to check local data before show Notification (check if there is data that need to sync). However, sometime device cannot receive Silent Notification (I still haven't found out reason for this issue).

I think this is bad solution but I don't have any way for now.

Comment: Don't know why sometime device cannot receive Silent Notification and it may caused by different kind of causes. Apple is always strict to background tasks unless you regesiter to run in the background.

Comment: I think I cannot do my app same as Facebook Messenger (sync in background) :)).  iOS Background task, it is too difficult. Maybe will spent time for this later.
If you have a better solution, please post at here so everyone can refer.Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Ok, will update here if I find a solution:).

Answer (score 0):

Reading through what you have written, I would say you should take a look into these possible solutions:

- [long-running
  task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks)
- [background-fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/updating-an-application-in-the-background)
- [NSUrlSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/background-transfer-walkthrough)

The code you provided is not the problem in this case. iOS and the way it handles backgrounding is what is your problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use background-fetch, but I don't know the exact time this method was executed (as document, OS will decide) so we will ignore this method.

I had took a look at long-running-task and NSUrlSession but I still don't know what should I do to solve issue. It doesn't mention the app receive Silent Notification is pushed from server (I want sync data between device and server every 5 minutes). So could you please give me an example or specific documents to solve?

Here is code that I handle when app receive Silent Notification (I will post at second comment)

Comment: CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
{
    SyncData();
};

private void SyncData()
        {
            if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                var service = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<ISyncService>();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    service.SyncSurveys();
                });
            }
        }

Comment: Maybe the solution I'm implementing right now is incorrect.
Hope you can give me a right solution or some idea so I can follow it.